# Android Xamarin.Auth 1.2.2 How to Update Uploaded Cloud Storage File LastModifiedDate?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

With Xamarin.Forms, I am using OneDrive SDK on UWP to access OneDrive and it is working good. I am uploading/downloading small data files and I use the following code to change a file's LastModifiedDate:

```
Item itemUpdate1 = new Item();
itemUpdate1.FileSystemInfo = new Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.FileSystemInfo {LastModifiedDateTime = lastModifiedDateTime };
await oneDriveClient1.Drive.Items[item1.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(itemUpdate1);
```

On Android, I use Xamarin.Auth to access OneDrive and I cannot figure out how to update a file's LastModifiedDate. I am using the following code to sign in and upload the file:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId: clientId, scope: storageScopes1, authorizeUrl: new System.Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf"),
  redirectUrl: new System.Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"));

System.Uri dataFileUri = new System.Uri("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/approot:/" + dataFileName1 + ":/content");
var requestUpload = new OAuth2Request("PUT", dataFileUri, null, account);
```

I would like to know if OAuth2Request can be used to update the file's LastModifiedDate or if there is another way to do it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Xamarin.Auth is only to handle the Authentication between your App and the OneDrive Rest Api.

If you want to modify any of the properties of a file in OneDrive you will need to either use a OneDrive SDK for Android as you do in the UWP project or do these modification using the Rest API directly as you did to upload the file.

***UPDATE 1***

```
System.Uri dataFileUri = new System.Uri("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/approot:/" + dataFileName1 + ":/content");
var requestUpload = new OAuth2Request("PUT", dataFileUri, null, account);
```

As you did in the code above, if you can get the endpoint for the OneDrive REST API to modify the file's properties (like LastModifiedDate) you could be able do it with `OAuth2Request`.

Go to the [OneDrive Dev Portal](https://dev.onedrive.com/) and try to get that information from the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am using Xamarin.Auth's OAuth2Request to upload the file so I thought there might be a way to use OAuth2Request to update the file modified date. I tried the OneDriveSDK for android but I could not get the Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication to work for Android so I thought if I could do it all with Xamarin.Auth in Android that I could possibly use Xamarin.Auth for UWP also and eliminate the OneDriveSDK or if I could use Xamarin.Auth authentication account as OneDriveClient then I could use OneDriveSDK for all but authentication and that would work great.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Following your recommendation, I revisited the onedrive.com documentation and found a page that I had not read.  According to https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_post.htm, there is a way to change the lastModifiedDateTime using Multipart Upload. I attempted to create a string that I could use to update the lastModifiedDateTime. My problem is that I do not know where to place this update string. Should it be placed in the Body or just added on to the end of the uri? I tried both ways with little success. I receive bad request most of the time.